# How to get back to the beginning of a file in a perl one-liner?

Tags: perl, filehandle

After going through a file once, I would like to go back to the beginning of the file and remove entries based on my original pass through the file, but I do not know how to go back to the beginning of the file.  I have the name of the input file to the one-liner but not the filehandle.  Do I need to have the filehandle?  How do I get it from the filename?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the one-liner? There are several possible ways how to process a file, [seeking](http://p3rl.org/seek) might or might not be possible.

Comment: my $command = 'perl -pi.bak -e \'my %commits; my @commits_to_delete; my @commits_to_edit; $/="=================================================================";
                                   if ($. == 2)                {    # Deleted code because of character limit. }
#                                      I want to go back through the file here.  I only work from the first "=================================================================" to the second.                                        
                                   } \' RELEASE_LOG_EXAMPLE.bak';

Comment: There's no easy way to seek with `-i`.

Comment: If you are trying to run this oneliner in an existing Perl program, consider using [Path::Tiny's edit_lines_utf8](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#edit_lines,-edit_lines_utf8,-edit_lines_raw) instead, it's similar in implementation and purpose to the perl -i switch. But since you need to seek around [edit_utf8](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#edit,-edit_raw,-edit_utf8) could instead be used to operate on the whole file as a string.

Comment: @choroba  I see a concern but it works for me (see answer)

Comment: You're usually better off just loading the file into memory.

Comment: @user2697302: Please don't dump code in a comment like that. It's much better if you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52729767/edit) to add more information.

Answer (score 1):

The filehandle is [ARGV](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#ARGV).  While `-i` may raise questions about seeking, it works in my tests

```
perl -i.bak -pe'
    $_ = "line: $_"; 
    if ($. == 2) { seek ARGV, 0, 0 }
' test.txt
```

If you see issues with `-i` or the backup (I don't) run without them and do that manually.

With the `-p` [switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) the `$_` is printed every time through.  Code shown in the comment uses it but the question seems to imply that not every line need be printed, as it wants to "*remove entries*" from the beginning.  If that is the case then use `-n` instead of `-p`, which also opens the file and iterates over its lines but does not print.  Then add print statements as needed.

It is generally a very good idea to read [I/O Operators in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators), and once you are mucking about with this I'd really recommend it.

It appears that there may be better approaches for your problem but we'd need more detail.

Comment: You can't "unprint" lines printed in the first pass. `-n` will be needed instead.

Comment: @choroba Right, but they gave `-p` in a comment.  I am hoping for feedback.  Added a comment, thank you.